# MOS Current Mirror

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-mirror

[image]

I was investigating a MOS current mirror on the photo however i could not understand how the equation (3) was obtained from equation (2). I put a question mark also there on the photo.

My second question is that the main advantage of connecting base and collector in a current mirror. What are the advantages of using current mirrors? If you share your idea i will be happy.

(There must be a connection between drain and gate of M1. I forgot to draw it.)

Comment: To answer your second question, we use current mirrors and diff pairs to create operational amplifiers and other integrated circuits like the famous LM386. [Look at this diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgM9E.jpg) While this isn't a MOS current mirror or diff pair but you can do it with MOS devices.

Comment: Thank you @KingDuken If we do not put the connection between drain and gate what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a connection between drain and gate for you current mirror to work properly.

To answer your question, the step from (2) to (3) involves an approximation. The term \$\lambda Vds\$ is usually quite small, and therefore 
$$
  \frac{1}{1+\lambda V_{ds1}} \approx 1 - \lambda V_{ds1}$$
in the next step (after multiplication) the the term \$ \lambda^2 V_{ds2} V_{ds1} \$ is neglected which results in the approximation
$$
(1 + \lambda V_{ds2}) (1 - \lambda V_{ds1}) \approx 1 + \lambda (V_{ds2} - V_{ds1})
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to draw connection. You said that it could not work properly if a connection is not put between drain and gate. What is the reason of putting that connection? @Mario

Comment: The connection is needed to get the proper gate voltage depending on the input current, otherwise the gate would be floating.