# Proof of type for Current mirror and Early effect (Mosfet transistors)

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, current-source

Can anyone explain me how I can prove this equation below (4.19).I know that \$V_{GS1}=V_{GS2}\$ and assuming that M1,M2 is in saturation then \$ID=0.5kn(vov)^2(1+\frac{V_{DS}}{V_{A}})\$

[image]

[image]

Comment: The M2 has no way, at DC frequency, to affect the voltage on its gate. I like your derivation.

Comment: Thanks  analogsystemsrf.Can you advice me how to prove this equation(4.19)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer in the question by Mario:
[MOS Current Mirror](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/291739/mos-current-mirror)

and the relation:

[image]

We can arrive to the equation 4.19.

Hope this helps.